# Javascript Functions - Calling Two Function In A File

Tags: javascript

Question: Two Functions Return Different Data But After Calling Both Functions Receive Output From Last Function. Why?

> javascript

```
var printStudentInfo = function () {
    return 'Name';
  }

var printStudentTerritory = function () {
    return 'Age';
  }

printStudentInfo();    
printStudentTerritory();
```

Comment: If you print their output, both of them return data as expected. Try `console.log(printStudentInfo());
console.log(printStudentTerritory());`

Comment: Thanks Ajay, for console I know,  but why output is overriding for above code. Is there any example to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, Here's what `printStudentInfo(); printStudentTerritory();` suggest `let someVariable = printStudentInfo(); printStudentTerritory();` Since the last function returns 'age'. Your variable is assigned to 'age'